# find matching string in a file using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Using Python I would like to find strings in a file that matches this format YYYY-MM-DD

```
Here is how my sample file looks like
I want to find date 2016-01-01 ,2016-01-05
then I want to find 2016-01-17
then I want to find this date 2016-01-04
```

Output should be

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-05
2016-01-17
2016-01-04
```

below is the code I am using currently using but I can't find matching records , any help on this will be appreciated  ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv 
import re
pattern = re.compile("^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])$")
for i, line in enumerate(open('C:\\Work\\scripts\\logs\\CSI.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        print 'Found on line' % (i+1, match.groups())
```

Comment: replace `^`, `$` with `\b` ie `r'\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b'`

Comment: It still does not work /

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv 
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\b\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\b')
for i, line in enumerate(open('C:\\Work\\scripts\\logs\\CSI.txt')):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
        print 'Found on line' % (i+1, match.groups())

Answer (score 0):

I would remove ^( and $, because your dates don't seem separated :

```
re.compile("[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and datetime to get valid dates from string

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
string = "I want to find date 2016-01-01 ,2016-01-05"
pattern  = re.complie("[\d]{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
raw_dates = pattern.findall(string)
parsed_dates = []
for date in raw_dates:
   try:
      d = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
      parsed_dates.append(d)
   except:
      pass
print(parsed_dates)
```

output:

```
['2016-01-01', '2016-01-05']
```